# Real Ajax Uploader will not display in DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm at my wits end. I purchased the Real Ajax Uploader Source codes and it works great independently but when I try to display it in a DIV it screws up and show only one DIV and the JS in it doesn't work.  get no error messages nor does Firebug show any errors and all JS and CSS seem to show as expected.

***UPDATE

Okay I've tried everything i can find in the documentation and still no better results.

localhost/index.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
include 'include/_abcde.php';
include 'include/_fghij.php';
include 'include/_klmno.php';
include 'include/_pqrs.php';
include 'include/_tuvwxyz.php';
include 'include/db.php';
include 'include/links.php';
include 'include/profilefunc.php';
include 'include/adodb-time.inc.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');
session_start();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php    
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){ echo"<title>Alberta XChange - Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."</title>";}
    else {echo"<title>Alberta XChange - Welcome</title>";}
?>    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Coffee's Creations">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/baseTheme/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.all({toolbar:false});
    </script></head>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username'])&&!empty($_POST['user_pwd'])&&!empty($_POST['email'])){Register();}
if(!empty($_POST['usernamea'])&&!empty($_POST['passworda'])){Login();}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){LoggedIn();exit;}
else {LoginForm();}

?>
</body>
```

I have confirmed that all JS and CSS links work.

localhost/include/_tuvwxyz.php (the Upload function part)

```
function Upload()
{
    ?>
        <div id="uploader_div"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#uploader_div').ajaxupload({
            url:'uploader/upload.php',
            data:'asd=asd&qwe=123',
            thumbHeight:200,
            finish:function(files){
                console.log(files);
            }
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

localhost/uploader/upload.php is the location of the upload.php. Not going to post the code since its original. However, I cannot tell if upload.php is opening but I see no reason that it wont. Only thing i can figure is maybe because upload.php is being called from a function in localhost/include that I would need to set the url as ../uploader/upload.php but even that gives me nothing.

Comment: It consistently fails to display in the DIV as hoped no matter how I rewrite the code that follows. Works well on its own but loses something in the DIV. I'm welcome to any suggestions.

Comment: `I cannot tell if upload.php is opening` In the chrome developer tools on the network panel you should be able to see that a request is made to `upload.php`. Do you mean [this real ajax uploader](http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/)? Have you solved your problem?

Comment: The problem was partially resolved by the script creator. I can now get it to work perfectly offline on my localhost but not when its run from my site. Probably need to find a misdirection somewhere

Comment: Hi Steven. have you solved the last problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was double loading jquery. Remove the second and it runs perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it says:

> **dropArea =** **jQuery selector/DOM element**
>
> Set the drag and drop area for files. Default the area is the initial
>   container. Example can be set to dropArea:$('.class').

So in your case, I would try this:

dropArea: $('#drop_here')

Answer (score 0):

I know its not in the documentation but what happens when you wrap your ajaxupload script with dom ready, like this:

```
 $(function(){
  $('#uploader_div').ajaxupload({
  url:'../uploader/upload.php',
  dropArea: '#drop_here',
  remotePath:'example3/'
 });

 });
```

Comment: No change with that either :(

Comment: Is there a way to test whether the upload.php is even loading like alert('IT WORKED')?

Comment: Yes you could. Just wrap it with a <script> tag. Do you have a cloud server where we can look at the code?

Comment: Well the entire site is at albertaxchange.com. The uploader scripts include all javascript and css are located at albertaxchange.com/uploader. The function that calls it is located in albertaxchange.com/include/_tuvwxyz.php

Comment: According to the docs, you should load jQuery.js and ajaxupload-min.js in the head section for your html document? You don't have that structure nor the doctype. Your structure should be:
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  put the scripts here
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Actually it was in the uploader/index.php. I moved all teh scripts including the css to my root index.php and removed them all from teh uploader/index.php. but I get the same result. Just that cursed Drag and Drop box :(